# In Xcode, how to step into lambda function?

Tags: xcode, lambda

When debugging, and having a breakpoint at the function `call(mFunction(1))`, I press `step into`, but the debugger didn't step into the lambda function.

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::function<void(int)> mFunction;

    mFunction = [](int a ){
        a = 2;
    };
    mFunction(1); //breakpoint at this line
    return 0;
}
```

**solution 1:**

```
(lldb)settings set target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp ""
```

I have tried this, It works, but you will never want to debug again.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can find your solution is correct. Once you are finished you can change the regex back to it's original value to make the rest of the debugging more pleasent. For example:

```
(lldb) settings show target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp
target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp (regex) = ^std::
(lldb) settings set target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp ""
... debug ...
(lldb) settings set target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp "^std::"
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/hotwatermorning/1c13149705ccf6d3233a043012d0d164